# Android, how to scroll several ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have 3 `ListView` in the same layout and I  want all of them show all their rows, so I need one scroll to the 3 `ListViews`. I´ve tried to put something like...

```
ScrollView
  RelativeLayout
   ListView1
   ListView2
   ListView3
```

But the lists show just one row and a half instead all of their rows.

On the other hand, I also tried to use a scrollable `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` but it didn't work.

Any idea??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never ever encapsulate your `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. Because there's no point of putting a scrollable view within a scrollable container.

Besides, you should equally distribute your `LinearLayout` using `android:weightSum` and apply `android:layout_weight` to your ListViews.

Comment: Actually, the listview are inside a RelativeLayout. Is there any way to use a Relative or Linear as scroll??

Comment: Either your ListViews are in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, dont make your parent(s) layout scrollable. You should distribute the layout with some fixed dimensions and host your ListViews inside.

Answer (score -1):

Check This http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/

Put all your 
`ListView`
inside the `ScrollView`.

Comment: I did it, but it didn´t work, the lists shrink and show just one row and a half

Comment: Then I think u should put all your data into one list view

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion to you is that don't use multiple listview in single layout screen because this confuses user and make things complex for him/her.I dont think its a good idea to put multiple lists in a single screen becoz touch will become weird and using screen will become complex.You should think something else to display multiple lists together in a single screen like you can use [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html).You can also use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

Romain Guy(Google developer) is also accepting this fact in the following link that UI-design is questionable if you use multiple lists in single screen.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/77acd4e54120b777

I hope my answer will help you and will make you to think to change your UI-design.